# I can't run java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure if I need to paste my code here, but when I go to run my code I right click on the class object and it usually says run as java application, but now all it says is run configurations.

I'm using Eclise.

Here is al of my code.  I know it's a bracket placement issue

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Date {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    } 

    public Date(int theMonth, int theDay, int theYear) {
        month = checkMonth( theMonth );
        year = checkYear( theYear );
        day = checkDay( theDay );
        System.out.printf("Date object constructor for date %s\n", toString() );
    }

    private int checkYear(int testYear) {
        if ( testYear > 0 )
            return testYear;
        else {
            System.out.printf("Invalid year (%d) set to 1.\n", testYear );
            return 1;
        }
    }

    private int checkMonth( int testMonth ) {
        if ( testMonth > 0 && testMonth <= 12 )
            return testMonth;
        else {
            System.out.printf("Invalid month (%d) set to 1.\n", testMonth );
            return 1;
        }
    }


    private int checkDay( int testDay ) {
        int daysPerMonth[] = 
            { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        if ( testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[ month ] )
            return testDay;

        if ( month == 2 && testDay == 29 && ( year % 400 == 0 ||
            ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 ) ) )
            return testDay;

        System.out.printf( "Invalid day (%d) set to 1.\n", testDay );

        return 1;
    }

    public void nextDay() {
        int testDay = day + 1;
        if ( checkDay( testDay ) == testDay )
            day = testDay;
        else {
            day = 1;
            nextMonth();
        }
    }

    public void nextMonth() {
        if ( 12 == month )
            year++;
        month = month % 12 + 1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format( "%d/%d/%d", month, day, year );
    }
}

class DateTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        System.out.println( "Checking increment" );
        Date testDate = new Date( 03, 13, 2011 );

        for ( int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++ ) {
            testDate.nextDay();
            System.out.printf( "Incremented Date: %s\n", testDate.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code have `public static void main(String[] args)`?

Comment: No, I was rearranging some things within the code and might have deleted it.  I am new to java so I'm not sure what I deleted.  Your statement goes at the top right?  Do I put brackets after it.  Thanks

Comment: Be careful:    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
This is an empty main.

Comment: You should know that not intending your code is a horrible crime for people that come to read it. Being a beginner is not an excuse.

Comment: Your code has changed. You will have to place private int month;
private int day;
private int year;
above the main method.And your main must not include constructors and other methods.

Comment: I tried doing this and something is still not right.  Now when I run it a box pops up that says Select java application.  Then it has a couple of choices: Date and DateTest.  I've tried looking at other examples, but can't figure it out.  I have edited the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Please remove the following lines of code (inside your `Date` class).

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
2. Make sure that class `Date` is found inside Date.java and `DateTest` is found inside DateTest.java (as you can see that each class name starts with a Capital Letter and the name of the class is **exactly** the same as the file name *with a .java extension*). In `DateTest`, you'll have to import your `Date` class accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I remove public static void main(String[] args) I can't run the code.

Comment: That's because you have `DateTest` class in the same file `Date.java`, ie. both classes are on the same file. Separate both classes as I mentioned on point 2.

Comment: That's my problem, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Create 2 files (as pointed on number 2). Each class has its own file and run DateTest file (on Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Remember, in order to run a Java application, it must have a **main** method.  In particular, it must be declared as:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

When you **run** your program in Eclipse, what it is actually doing is executing all the code in main().  It will NOT execute any other methods/code unless you call it from main (or, of course, it is called indirectly through main).  Therefore if you want ANYTHING to happen, you'll need to put what you want to actually do in main.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

when run via Eclipse, will print "Hello World!" and finish.  Whatever stuff you want to do with the Date class should then go in that method too.

Comment: I tried enclosing everything in the brackets, but then I get tons of errors.

Comment: Of course, the other stuff doesn't belong in the brackets, they belong to the Date class.  The main method just EXECUTES whatever is in it.  For example, in main you can create a Date, and print the Date.  In other words, don't change any of the outside stuff!  Just put code in main that performs the actions you desire.

Answer (score 0):

you changed your code - so I edit my answer:

get rid of the main method in the Date class and make your Date Test class public.

```
public class { ... }
```

is the DateTest class stored in a File called DateClass.java?